# Leaflet: resize bindPopup

Tags: javascript, leaflet

How can I change the size of the bindPopup since when opening the web from a mobile phone it is very large, in the image that shows a lot of space is left below, is there any way to reduce that size?
search the internet but there are no results almost everything is from the bookmarks

[image: Popup with too much white-space]

This is part of the code I use to display this information:

```js
const updateMap = () => {
            const Buslocation =
              "https:xxxxxxxxxxxxx" + gtebi;
            fetch(Buslocation)
              .then((res) => res.json())
              .then((data) => {
                //si existe el marcador removerlo para no tener marcadores duplicados
                if (bus_marker) {
                  map.removeLayer(bus_marker);
                  
                }
                //asignar valores que se usaran ingresar el marcador
                const latitud = data.latitud;
                const longitud = data.longitud;
                //asignar valores que se usaran mas adelate para definir el popup
                const destino = data.destino;
                const origen = data.origen;
                const patente = data.patente;
                //animacion para dirigirse al punto donde se encuentra el bus
                map.flyTo([latitud, longitud], 12);
                //crear marcador
                bus_marker = L.marker([latitud, longitud], {
                  icon: busicon,
                })
                  .addTo(map)
                  .bindPopup(
                    "<strong><h3>El bus esta aquí</h3></strong>" +
                      "<h5>Origen: " +
                      "<strong>" +
                      origen +
                      "</strong>" +
                      "</h5>" +
                      "<h5>Destino: " +
                      "<strong>" +
                      destino +
                      "</strong>" +
                      "</h5>" +
                      "<h5>Patente: " +
                      "<strong>" +
                      patente +
                      "</strong>" +
                      "</h5>"
                  )
                  .update();
              });
              //definir el tiempo de actualizacion del marcador(bus)
            setTimeout(updateMap, 180000);
          };
```

I searched the internet but I only get options for the map markers.

or if I can remove the bindPopup somehow, because if I don't use it, the white bar is left next to it.

[image: white bar instead of pop-up]

Comment: I have very forgotten leaflet but it does not allow you to change the styles with css in responsive with the width of the device?

Comment: You can edit your question to add extra information, don't use the answer for that. If I run your code, I get a small popup, but I don't know what is in your `patente` variable. Maybe it contains a lot of empty lines? Do you have a css style defined? maybe that has parameters for the popups too